# Kafka Spark Streaming Error - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/connector/read/streaming/ReportsSourceMetrics

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using **Spark 3.1.2, Kafka 2.8.1 & Scala 2.12.1**

Getting below Error while integrating Kafka and Spark streaming -

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/connector/read/streaming/ReportsSourceMetrics**

Spark-shell command with Dependency - spark-shell --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2

```
 org.apache.spark#spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12 added as a dependency
 :: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-3643b83d-a2f8-43d1-941f-a125272f3905;1.0
         confs: [default]
         found org.apache.spark#spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12;3.1.2 in central
         found org.apache.spark#spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12;3.1.2 in central
         found org.apache.kafka#kafka-clients;2.6.0 in central
         found com.github.luben#zstd-jni;1.4.8-1 in central
         found org.lz4#lz4-java;1.7.1 in central
         found org.xerial.snappy#snappy-java;1.1.8.2 in central
         found org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.30 in central
         found org.spark-project.spark#unused;1.0.0 in central
         found org.apache.commons#commons-pool2;2.6.2 in central
 :: resolution report :: resolve 564ms :: artifacts dl 9ms
         :: modules in use:
         com.github.luben#zstd-jni;1.4.8-1 from central in [default]
         org.apache.commons#commons-pool2;2.6.2 from central in [default]
         org.apache.kafka#kafka-clients;2.6.0 from central in [default]
         org.apache.spark#spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12;3.1.2 from central in [default]
         org.apache.spark#spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12;3.1.2 from central in [default]
         org.lz4#lz4-java;1.7.1 from central in [default]
         org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.30 from central in [default]
         org.spark-project.spark#unused;1.0.0 from central in [default]
         org.xerial.snappy#snappy-java;1.1.8.2 from central in [default]
         ---------------------------------------------------------------------
         |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
         |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
         ---------------------------------------------------------------------
         |      default     |   9   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   9   |   0   |
         ---------------------------------------------------------------------
 :: retrieving :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-3643b83d-a2f8-43d1-941f-a125272f3905
         confs: [default]
         0 artifacts copied, 9 already retrieved (0kB/15ms)
 21/12/28 17:46:21 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
 Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
 Setting default log level to "WARN".
 To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
 21/12/28 17:46:28 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
 Spark context Web UI available at http://*******:4041
 Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1640693788919).
 Spark session available as 'spark'.
 Welcome to
       ____              __
      / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
     _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
    /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.1.2
       /_/
 
 Using Scala version 2.12.10 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_292)
 Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
 Type :help for more information.
    
    val df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "127.0.1.1:9092").option("subscribe", "Topic").option("startingOffsets", "earliest").load()
    
    df.printSchema()
    
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
    val schema = new StructType().add("id",IntegerType).add("fname",StringType).add("lname",StringType)
    val personStringDF = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
    val personDF = personStringDF.select(from_json(col("value"), schema).as("data")).select("data.*")
     
    personDF.writeStream.format("console").outputMode("append").start().awaitTermination()
    
    Exception in thread "stream execution thread for [id = 44e8f8bf-7d94-4313-9d2b-88df8f5bc10f, runId = 3b4c63c4-9062-4288-a681-7dd6cfb836d0]" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/connector/read/streaming/ReportsSourceMetrics
```

Answer (score 3):

Spark_version 3.1.2

Scala_version 2.12.10

Kafka_version 2.8.1

**Note:** The versions are very important when we use `--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:V.V.V` with either `spark-shell` or `spark-submit`. Where `(V.V.V = Spark_version)`

I followed the following steps as given at [spark-kafka-example](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-streaming-with-kafka/):

1. start producer
   `$ kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list Kafka-Server-IP:9092  --topic kafka-spark-test`

You should see the prompt `>` on console. Enter some test data on producer.

```
>{"name":"foo","dob_year":1995,"gender":"M","salary":2000}
>{"name":"bar","dob_year":1996,"gender":"M","salary":2500}
>{"name":"baz","dob_year":1997,"gender":"F","salary":3500}
>{"name":"foo-bar","dob_year":1998,"gender":"M","salary":4000}
```

2. Start the `spark-shell` as follows:

```
spark-shell --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2
```

Notice: i have used 3.1.2. You will see something like following on successful start:

```
Spark session available as 'spark'.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.1.2
      /_/
         
Using Scala version 2.12.10 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 11.0.13)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
```

3. Enter the imports and create DataFrame, and print the schema.

```
val df = spark.readStream.
      format("kafka"). 
      option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "Kafka-Server-IP:9092").
      option("subscribe", "kafka-spark-test").
      option("startingOffsets", "earliest").
      load()

df.printSchema()
```

4. The successful execution should result following:

```
scala> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- key: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- value: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- topic: string (nullable = true)
 |-- partition: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- offset: long (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- timestampType: integer (nullable = true)
```

5. Convert binary values of DataFrame to string. I am showing command with output

```
scala>      val personStringDF = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")


personStringDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: string]
```

6. Make and schema for DataFrame. I am showing command with output

```
scala> val schema = new StructType().
     |       add("name",StringType).
     |       add("dob_year",IntegerType).
     |       add("gender",StringType).
     |       add("salary",IntegerType)


schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(name,StringType,true), StructField(dob_year,IntegerType,true), StructField(gender,StringType,true), StructField(salary,IntegerType,true))
```

7. Select the data

```
scala>  val personDF = personStringDF.select(from_json(col("value"), schema).as("data")).select("data.*")

personDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, dob_year: int ... 2 more fields]
```

8. Write the stream on console

```
scala>  personDF.writeStream.
     |       format("console").
     |       outputMode("append").
     |       start().
     |       awaitTermination()
```

You will see the following output:

```
-------------------------------------------                                     
Batch: 0
-------------------------------------------
+-------+--------+------+------+
|   name|dob_year|gender|salary|
+-------+--------+------+------+
|    foo|    1981|     M|  2000|
|    bar|    1982|     M|  2500|
|    baz|    1983|     F|  3500|
|foo-bar|    1984|     M|  4000|
+-------+--------+------+------+
```

If your kafka producer is still running, you may enter a new row and you will see the new data in Batch: 1 and so on for each time you enter new data in producers.

This is a typical example when we enter data from console producer and consume in spark console.

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

I had nearly the same problem - same exception but in `spark-submit`.
I solved it by upgrading Spark to version `3.2.0`.
I also used version `3.2.0` of `org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12` with the full command being:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.2.0 script.py
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will upgrade to the latest and give a try.

Answer (score 0):

just check your spark version with `spark.version` and adjust the packages as suggested in the other answers.